# svn ci multiline message log/text file with log message

Tags: svn, logging, message, commit

I have this problem when I do

```
svn ci -m "Message text multiline" dir/
```

I want the log message to look like:

```
fixed:
-bug 1
-bug 2
-bug 3
```

Instead I get:

```
fixed: -bug 1-bug 2- bug 3
```

This is caused because I can't insert a newline (\n\r) in the log message.

I use putty for the SVN. I searched a little bit and I saw that for the echo command there is a solution:

```
echo -e "new\n\rline"
```

will output:

```
new
line
```

Also I saw there is a way instead of `-m "message"` to specify a text.txt file where I can put the log already formatted, but I didn't find an example.

Can somebody help me fix this issue, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that you can add new line even with svn ci -m, it will work only if you wrote down only one coma :
[good] - svn ci -m "press enter then close coma.

[bad] - svn ci -m "" dir/ (and then add the text with new lines)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`-F`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.file) option to specify the log message file instead of `-m`:

```
svn ci -F logmessage.txt dir/
```

See another example of using it in [the documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.commit.html).