# multi-lines in svn log with GUI

Tags: user-interface, svn

How can I use the **multi-lines** for `tortoise svn log` in the User-interface in windows?

> I want the log message to look like:
>
> ```
> fixed:
> -bug 1
> -bug 2
> -bug 3
> ```
>
> Instead I get:
>
> ```
> fixed: -bug 1-bug 2- bug 3
> ```

Link:
[svn ci multiline message log/text file with log message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26846207/svn-ci-multiline-message-log-text-file-with-log-message)

Comment: I already tried `\n` but it didn't work

Comment: Are you realyl asking about TortoiseSVN. TortoiseSVN provides rich editor for commit log messages: https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-commit.html#tsvn-dug-commit-log If you ask about CLI, learn how to enter newline in cmd.exe.

Comment: Yes, I use TortoiseSVN. I have to use  version 1.7.10.  Where am I able to see the changes? Inside the "Log messages" window or only in some other window like "Revision Graph"?

Comment: Multi-lines are not visible in `Log messages` That's where I want to have them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 lines or more, you have to separate them with an empty line. This way you make sure only the first line will be shown.